# Loops and map references

Tags: loops, pointers, go

I have code that loops over an array of `Task` and creates a Map with string keys and `Task` values:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Task struct {
    Name    string
    Project string
}

func main() {
    taskMap := map[string]*Task{}
    taskList := []Task{
        {
            Name:    "name1",
            Project: "project1",
        },
        {
            Name:    "name2",
            Project: "project2",
        },
        {
            Name:    "name3",
            Project: "project3",
        },
    }
    for _, task := range taskList {
        taskMap[task.Name] = &task
    }

    // Print results
    for k, v := range taskMap {
        fmt.Println(k, v)
    }
}
```

The output for this code is the following:

```
name1 &{name3 project3}
name2 &{name3 project3}
name3 &{name3 project3}
```

This is not what I expected, since it is printing the same every time. I have a slight clue of what is going on here, because if I replace the loop with the following, it works as expected:

```
for _, task := range taskList {
        taskMap[task.Name] = &Task{
            Name:        task.Name,
            Project: task.Project,
        }
}
```

So somehow the reference to the last visited task is the one that ends up stored in every key of `taskMap`, apparently.

Is there a way to do this without resorting to copying each field manually?

Comment: Variable `task` stores a local copy which changes in each iteration, but the address of `task` (which is stored in the map) stays the same. So, when you print the map contents, all map values point to the copy of the last list item.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get the same value for all keys cause you are referencing the same `task` variable in your `for` loop. Use following snippet to get references to items in your slice.

```
for idx, task := range taskList {
    taskMap[task.Name] = &taskList[idx]
}
```

BTW to (shallow) copy a variable you can assign it to a new variable like

```
for _, task := range taskList {
    x := task
    taskMap[task.Name] = &x
}
```

a new `x` variable will be created in each iteration and a pointer to that will be used inside the map.

Comment: I'd say the proper solution would be `for i := range taskList { taskMap[taskName] = &taskList[i] }`. I mean, if one wants to get a pointer to an element of the slice on each iteration, there's no point in obtaining the element itself — its index would suffice, and it can easily be used to obtain a pointer to its corresponding element.

Comment: Except that in your example `taskName` doesn't exist; you need the element to get the name. The posted solution seems correct to me.

Comment: It's not hard to "make it exist". No, really.

Comment: Ooooor you could just use the two-argument form of the `range` operator and not have to use an intermediate variable or an additional slice identifier.  Seriously, why make this harder than it needs to be.  The two-arg form is perfectly appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

You're storing the address of `task` rather than the value.

You can instead switch `taskList` to a slice of pointers: `taskList := []*Task{` and use `taskMap[task.Name] = task`.

Comment: Actually I like Arman's answer better than mine, it shows you how to do it without changing the existing data structure. Mine is acceptable in this scenario but you don't always control what comes in.